# Factual conditionals: simple present or future?

Tags: conditional-constructions

At times I find it difficult to decide whether to use a zero conditional sentence or a first conditional. Would you mind helping me with the following example:

> If they want to get there fast, they ....... (take/will take) the
>   express train.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question might be more appropriate for ELL.SE. Categorizing conditional sentences like this is specific to learning English as a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you are talking about an habitual event or predicting a future event.

> If they want to get there fast, they take the express train.

In this case, taking the express is an habitual consequence of needing to get there fast. *If* can be replaced by *whenever*.

On the other hand, if you are speculating on how they will get somewhere in the future, then you say:

> If they want to get there fast, they will take the express train.

In this case, *if* cannot be replaced by *whenever*, and *will* cannot be omitted.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to use *would* here.

> If they want to get there fast, they *would* take the express train.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect unless you use a past tense in the _if clause_: `If they wanted to get there fast, they would take the express train.`